# How to Dynamic change paper format margins (Left, Right, Top, Bottom)?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to change my report paper size dynamically while printing pdf report. Like I have type in my object. When type change then, I want to change my report margin(top, bottom, left, right) which value configure as per margin.

Thanks for your valuable help

Answer (score 1):

You can override the method that calls `wkhtmltopdf` and manipulate the parameters passed there. See `odoo.addons.report.models.report.get_pdf` function. You can override this, check your variable and call `_run_wkhtmltopdf` with different arguments.

It does not sound like a good idea though and you would be better off creating multiple paper format records and using them accordingly

Comment: Yes, but I have to use only one paper format for all and dynamically record wise change paper format. what in get_pdf method

Comment: In `get_pdf` method you can get the record of your model you are printing for. Then you can check in that record whether it contains the value that you want and then you can calculate the margins and pass them in the `_run_wkhtmltopdf` on `spec_paperformat_args`